# Unity cannot build android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I was upgrading my unity from 2020.3.30f1 to 2021.3.24f1 and trying to build Android App Bundle
Minimum API Level 21, target API Level 33
but always failed with this message, any help and guidance would help me a lot
thank you

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.30f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.30f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Note: /Users/felix/Repository/recogame/RecoUnity/Temp/gradleOut/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
```

1: Task failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
/Users/felix/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/dcabf090caecffb1d02527a5ebf491a6/jetified-unity-ads-4.7.0/AndroidManifest.xml:52:9-54:58: AAPT: error: unexpected element <property> found in <manifest><application>.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

2: Task failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:bundleReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
/Users/felix/Repository/recogame/RecoUnity/Temp/gradleOut/launcher/build/intermediates/bundle_manifest/release/bundle-manifest/AndroidManifest.xml:239: AAPT: error: unexpected element <property> found in <manifest><application>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
]
stdout[

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources FAILED
> Task :launcher:bundleReleaseResources FAILED

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
56 actionable tasks: 46 executed, 10 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:337)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

Trying to update android studio and clear gradle but still cannot build
```

Comment: Do you need the unity ads?

Comment: I only use Unity Advertisement with Mediation and I can build it yesterday before I upgrade from 2020.3.30f1 to 2021.3.24f1

Comment: You are still using JDK in the Unity2020 folder, maybe you need to take a look at the Unity preferences.

Comment: I've resolved the problem for now, the Unity Advertisement with Mediation using dependency to Unity Ads 4.7.0 (released 4 Days ago) and I think i've enabled "Enable Resolution On Build", so I try to use OverrideDependencies.xml to set the version to 4.6.1
Thank you for your help anyway!